# Are some laws "Progressive" for businesses?

Tags: law

(United States Based)
I'm not sure if this is the right exchange to ask this in. You know how there are progressive tax laws where lower income individuals are taxed a smaller percent of their income. Is this usually done with respect to companies and their profit margin?  Are laws often written so that regulations and stipulations are lesser for "smaller" businesses? If not, why? Also, are there any laws where businesses trying to enter markets with high barriers to entry are subsidized in order to encourage competition in said market?